# sonarQube reporting bug - make field transient or serializable

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube, sonarlint

I am getting below bug after running sonarqube analysis i am getting error

> Make "getPreAHistFlt" transient or serializable "

How can we resolve this issue?

code snippet:

```
package com.sanju.p1; 
//webfault and namespace
@WebFault(name = "getPreAHistFlt", targetNamespace = "http://www.getPreAuthorizationHistory") 
public class getPreAHistFltMsg extends Exception { 

    private com.sanju.p2.GetPreAHistFlt getPreAHistFlt;   // showing bug here 
//constructors
    public getPreAHistFltMsg() { 
        super(); 
    } 

    public getPreAHistFltMsg(String message) { 
        super(message); 
    } 

    public getPreAHistFltMsg(String message, Throwable cause) { 
        super(message, cause); 
    } 

    public getPreAHistFltMsg(String message, com.sanju.p2.GetPreAHistFlt getPreAHistFlt) { 
        super(message); 
        this.getPreAHistFlt = getPreAHistFlt; 
    } 

    public getPreAHistFltMsg(String message, com.sanju.p2.GetPreAHistFlt getPreAHistFlt, Throwable cause) { 
        super(message, cause); 
        this.getPreAHistFlt = getPreAHistFlt; 
    } 

    public com.sanju.p2.GetPreAHistFlt getFaultInfo() { 
        return this.getPreAHistFlt; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getPreAHistFltMsg extends Exception`, which is a subclass of `Throwable`; `Throwable` implements `Serializable`, so all subclasses of `Throwable` also implement `Serializable` transitively.

Presumably, `com.sanju.p2.GetPreAHistFlt` does not implement `Serializable`. As such, if you tried to serialize a `getPreAHistFltMsg` where that field is non-null, it would fail, because that field's value cannot be serialized.

Either:

- Exclude the field from the serialization by making it `transient`;
- Make `GetPreAHistFlt` implement `Serializable` (but pay heed to the *Effective Java* item about why implementing `Serializable` is something that you should think carefully before doing);
- Extract the relevant (serializable) fields from it.

Comment: GetPreAHistFlt  (stub) this class got generated via wsdl So if we make this serializable will this effect at the other end ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the simplest way to solve it would be to change your class GetPreAHistFlt  to implement the Serializable interface.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making the class GetPreAHistFlt as serializable.